# Google Tag Manager clickstream to Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, bigdata

So the questions has more to do with what services should i be using to have the efficient performance.

**Context and goal:**

So what i trying to do exactly is use tag manager custom HTML so after each Universal Analytics tag (event or pageview) send to my own EC2 server a HTTP request with a similar payload to what is send to Google Analytics.

**What i think, planned and researched so far:**

At this moment i have two big options,

- Use [Kinesis](https://sa-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/home?region=sa-east-1#/) AWS which seems like a great idea but the problem is that it only drops the information in one redshift table and i would like to have at least 4 o 5 so i can differentiate pageviews from events etc ... My solution to this would be to divide from the server side each request to a separated stream.
- The other option is to use Spark + Kafka. ([Here is a detail explanation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/real-time-stream-processing-using-apache-spark-streaming-and-apache-kafka-on-aws/))

I know at some point this means im making a parallel Google Analytics with everything that implies. I still need to decide what information (im refering to which parameters as for example the source and medium) i should send, how to format it correctly, and how to process it correctly.

**Questions and debate points:**

1. Which options is more efficient and easiest to set up?
2. Send this information directly from the server of the page/app or send it from the user side making it do requests as i explained before.
3. Does anyone did something like this in the past? Any personal recommendations?

Answer (score -1):

You'd definitely benefit from Google Analytics custom task feature instead of custom HTML. More on this from [Simo Ahava.](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/send-google-analytics-tag-multiple-properties/) Also, Google Big Query is quite a popular destination for streaming hit data since it allows many 'on the fly computations such as sessionalization and there are many ready-to-use cases for BQ.

Comment: Thanks for the data. I knew about the customTask in fields to set but it may come handy to people of the future.